# Trying to read a matrix of character one character at a time

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I am trying to read the following input and assign the matrix from the input to a char matrix. The problem is, when I output the matrix, it outputs the character in a strange manner. What am I doing wrong?

Input:

```
10 10
PPPPPPPPPP
PXXXXTPXXP
PXPPPPXXXP
PXXXPJPPXP
PPPXPXXXXP
CXXXXXPXPP
PXPXXXPXXP
PXPPPPPXXP
PXXXXXXXXP
PPPPPPPPPP
```

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream in("tom.in");
    ofstream out("tom.out");
    int n, m;
    char s[101][101];
    in>>n>>m; //read the size of the matrix
    for(int i = 1; i<=n; i++)
        for(int j = 1; j<=m; j++)
            in.get(s[i][j]); //assign each element from the file to the matrix

    for(int i = 1; i<=n; i++)
    {
        out<<endl;
        for(int j = 1; j<=m; j++)
            out<<s[i][j];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
PPPPPPPPP
P
PXXXXTPX
XP
PXPPPPX
XXP
PXXXPJ
PPXP
PPPXP
XXXXP
CXXX
XXPXPP
PXP
XXXPXXP
PX
PPPPPXXP
P
XXXXXXXXP
```

The IDE I am using is Codeblocks.

Comment: Regarding `for(int i = 1; i<=n; i++)` Remember that arrays are origin 0. Messing around with this and going origin 1 can lead to a lot of pain.

Comment: [Also remember that `get` is unformatted input.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get). That means some of the fun things `>>` did for you won't happen here.

Comment: Trying to fake 1-based arrays in C++ invariably leads to bugs, either out-of-bounds accesses, or using the `0` index of the array by mistake.  Just use arrays as intended in C++, and that is to use indexing from `0` to `n-1`, where `n` is the number of entries.

Comment: The programming problem I am trying to solve requires me to index  them from 1 to n, so that is why I did it. Also, even if I indexed it from 0, I don't think it would've solved the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
in.get(s[i][j]);
```

with

```
in >> s[i][j];
```

Explanation:

Let's take a look at what is going on by printing out exactly what was read, but as numbers we can compare against an ASCII table:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream in("tom.in");
    ofstream out("tom.out");
    int n, m;
    char x;
    in>>n>>m; //read the size of the matrix
    for(int i = 1; i<=n; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 1; j<=m; j++)
        {
            in.get(x);
            cout << (int)x <<  ' ';
        }
        cout << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This results in

```
10 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 
80 10 80 88 88 88 88 84 80 88 
88 80 10 80 88 80 80 80 80 88 
88 88 80 10 80 88 88 88 80 74 
80 80 88 80 10 80 80 80 88 80 
88 88 88 88 80 10 67 88 88 88 
88 88 80 88 80 80 10 80 88 80 
88 88 88 80 88 88 80 10 80 88 
80 80 80 80 80 88 88 80 10 80 
88 88 88 88 88 88 88 88 80 10
```

Right off the bat we have a 10. That doesn't map to a latin character like P, T, J, or X. It's a '\n'. A newline.

Checking [the documentation for `std::istream::get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) we find `get` is [an unformatted input function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/UnformattedInputFunction). It is not stripping out whitespace for you the way you may be used to.

We can add some code to strip out the line endings, but why bother? A formatted input function will do that for us.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream in("tom.in");
    ofstream out("tom.out");
    int n, m;
    char x;
    in>>n>>m; //read the size of the matrix
    for(int i = 1; i<=n; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 1; j<=m; j++)
        {
            in >> x; //  MADE CHANGE HERE
            cout << (int)x <<  ' ';
        }
        cout << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now the output looks like

```
80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 
80 88 88 88 88 84 80 88 88 80 
80 88 80 80 80 80 88 88 88 80 
80 88 88 88 80 74 80 80 88 80 
80 80 80 88 80 88 88 88 88 80 
67 88 88 88 88 88 80 88 80 80 
80 88 80 88 88 88 80 88 88 80 
80 88 80 80 80 80 80 88 88 80 
80 88 88 88 88 88 88 88 88 80 
80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80
```

which, when converted back to ASCII charracters is the expected

```
PPPPPPPPPP
PXXXXTPXXP
PXPPPPXXXP
PXXXPJPPXP
PPPXPXXXXP
CXXXXXPXPP
PXPXXXPXXP
PXPPPPPXXP
PXXXXXXXXP
PPPPPPPPPP
```

Comment: If you want to read the whitespace, go back to `get` or [use `std::noskipws`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/skipws)

Comment: If I go back to 'get', it'll mess up the matrix again, so I guess I'll take 'noskipws'

Comment: If you want spaces and not the line endings, look into `std::getline` Read the whole line and then split it up any way you want. `std::istringstream` can be helpful here.

Answer (score 0):

You can read first the lengths of the multi-dimensional array and then iterate over all the content filling the array up.

```
std::ifstream in("data.txt");
std::ofstream out("tom.txt");

int n, m;
// verify the lengths
in >> m >> n;
std::cout << n << ", " << m << std::endl;


char** data = new char*[n];
for(auto i(0); i != n; ++i)
    data[i] = new char[m];

for(auto i(0); i != n; ++i)
    for(auto j(0); j != m; ++j)
        in >> data[i][j];

for(auto i(0); i != n; ++i){
    for(auto j(0); j != m; ++j)
        std::cout << data[i][j]; // just to print to the screen. you can write to the second file with `out` object.
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

// clean

for(auto i(0); i != n; ++i)
    delete[]data[i];
delete[]data;

// close streams
in.close();
out.close();
```

As you can see above I read first `n` and `m` which are the lengths of the array Which means that the input pointer moves forward which means that next read will read from the line following lengths.

- The problem in your code is: `in.get()` reads a character at a time but it doesn't stop reading when reaching an `endline character`. Whereas `ifstream` object with the `extraction operator >>` discards it.